# How to write a Custom JPA method to search a database record using fields name

Tags: spring-boot

Here i am working in Spring Boot. Now i am creating API's for CRUD Operations. Also i need to write a code for Searching the database record using fields name. Here i am working with "Products" table. the table contains fields like "itemCode", "hsCode", "itemCategoryId","productDescription","brand","countryOfOrigin","uom","retailSellingPrice","exciseTaxPercentage","assignedTo","assignedBy",...etc.

```
     So, if the user gives the input as the brand, uom, retailSellingPrice. i should use a Query like "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE brand=:brand, uom =:uom,retailSellingPrice=:retailSellingPrice ".
```

I write a Custom JPA method like findByuomContainingOrRetailSellingPriceContainingOrBrandContaining(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);

But is there any other approach to search the products using fields so that if 10 searching fields is there, then my custom method will be small only.

Please give me some suggestions

Comment: Are you using default provided JPA repository or custom repository?

Comment: i am using default provided JPA repository (CrudRepository interface). There i am using custom JPA method

Comment: could you please add some code of your repository class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom repository and give method name whatever you want(a small one).

You can create a custom repository like below :

Assuming that you have a `ProductRepository implements CrudRepository<Product,Long>`

1. Create an interface like `#Your_repository_name{custom}` (**ProductRepositoryCustom**) and give method name whatever you want with required parameters.
2. Create implementation class for **ProductRepositoryCustom** interface. You can name it whatever you want, but it will be good if you follow some convention. Do it like #Your_repository_name{Impl} (**ProductRepositoryImpl**)
3. Extend `ProductRepositoryCustom` from `ProductRepository`(`ProductRepository implements CrudRepository<Product,Long>,ProductRepositoryCustom`)

Now you can call method of `ProductRepositoryImpl` from the same object you call the methods of `ProductRepository`.

```
@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;
```

Use `productRepository` to call methods of Impl clas.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JPA's **Query by Example**. `QueryByExampleExecutor` interface is extended by `JpaRepository`. It has a few methods for searching by example. Here is a simple example,

Let say `Product` is an entity representing `Products` table, then you can do something like this,

```
Product product = new Product();
product.setItemCode(...);
product.setHsCode(...);
...

Example<Product> example = Example.of(product);
Iterable<Product> = repository.findAll(example);
```

You can find a concrete example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/query-by-example).